# How do I fix this issue with viewing my model?

Tags: shaders, interface

So I am an ultimate beginner at blender and for some reason while editing my model, everything has become dark grey and there is no longer any shading/shadows/lighting. Does anyone know how to fix this so it looks back to normal?
[image: a visual representation of this issue]

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen the *Wireframe* shading mode, choose another one:

[image]